# Jest issue "ReferenceError: test is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a small issue with Jest and Webstorm. I saw other threads that explained that this problem was maybe related to the version of node.js or jest but for me they are all up to date.
This happen only when I tried to execute one test at the time but when do all of them it worked.

JEST VERSION
26.4.2

NODE VERSION
v14.9.0

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = sum;
```

```js
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});

test('adds 2 + 2 to equal 4', () => {
  expect(sum(2, 2)).toBe(4);
});

test('null', () => {
  const n = null;

  expect(n).toBeNull();
  expect(n).toBeDefined();
  expect(n).not.toBeUndefined();
  expect(n).not.toBeTruthy();
  expect(n).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Thank you

Comment: Without `package.json` file and the command you're using to run only one test it's not clear to post an answer.